# how to dowload and load .gif in android using volley?

Tags: android, android-volley, gif, android-json

i am using this gif library  https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable
to display gif in xml and gifImageView as view , i was using ImageRequest in volley to download gif from url . but the gif is shown as still image in app. cant figure out what happened ?pls help me with my code or  pls tell me how to download gif via volley.

variables defined:-

```
SwipeDeck cardSwipe;
String url = "";
ImageView iv;
RequestQueue que;
RequestQueue que2;
SwipeCardAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Bitmap> urls = new ArrayList<>();
```

this is stringRequest function block to fetch Json

```
public StringRequest strReq(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray dataObject = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                for(int i = 0 ; i < dataObject.length() ; i++){
                    JSONObject thisObject = dataObject.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject image = thisObject.getJSONObject("images");
                    JSONObject imageType = image.getJSONObject("original");
                    String imageUrl = imageType.getString("url");
                    Log.d("TAG", imageUrl);
                    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
                    que2.add(imageReq(imageUrl));

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("TAG","error occured in try and catch");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            if(error.getCause() != null){
                error.getCause().printStackTrace();
            }
            if(error.networkResponse != null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network Response is " + error.networkResponse , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });


            return stringRequest;
}
```

and this is the imageRequest function block to download gif from the url:-

```
public ImageRequest imageReq(String url){

        ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(url, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {

                urls.add(response);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



            }
        }, 0, 0, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                if(error.getCause() != null){
                    error.getCause().printStackTrace();
                }
                if(error.networkResponse != null){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network Response is " + error.networkResponse , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
        return imageRequest;
    }
```

and this inside the adapter class to set gifImageView:-

```
GifImageView gifImageView = (GifImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gifIV);


            Bitmap thisGif = getItem(position);

            gifImageView.setImageBitmap(thisGif);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure why you are using the GifDrawable Library the Glide Library is so much better. https://github.com/bumptech/glide

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(image.getMedium())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(holder.thumbnail);
```

Comment: thanks  a lot glide worked using  GlideDrawableImageViewTarget.

Comment: In addition if you read the samples you can extend glide pretty robustly, to start off DiskCacheStrategy is something you might want to look into as well

Comment: ya its pretty good i used placeholder to show a loading screen though i am not able to animate the loading yet but its good i used CrossFade and error , i will definitely look into  DiskCacheStrategy and apply it in my app .Thank you again

Comment: With glide3.7.0 it should properly animate with the above source once the image is loaded completely. You have two options depending on what works for you

Comment: 1 DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE and 2 replace .crossfade with .asGif,  Also could you be using a View from the gifdrawable library? This will animate into basic <ImageView> layouts      sorry I am on mobile

Comment: no problem at all . ya gifs are animating but i was using a loading_spinner.gif as placeholder that was not animating still looking into that .

Comment: do i have to explicitly write DiskCacheStratergy as i was reading Glide library it said that you don't need to do anything extra to activate caching ?

Comment: No you do not, but using it offers greater control over how your app preforms